# Woocommerce order empty items array

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I call `$order = new WC_Order(52);` and I get a correct order object but the Items array is empty.

I 've tried `select * from wp_woocommerce_order_items where order_id=52;` and I got the line item.

Any ideas whats going wrong ?

I am using WooCommerce 3.4.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fetch the order items you can use the method

```
get_items()
```

I am doing something similar to you and i am doing it like this

```
$order = wc_get_order($order_id);
$line_items = $order->get_items();
```

In WooCommerce 3.0, CRUD objects were added so all the data can be accessed using getters and set using setters. Line items are the same so when you have your line items you should loop them and access the data using getters.

For more information about the available getters and setters for these objects you can use this for reference https://docs.woocommerce.com/wp-content/images/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order.html for the order object and for the product line items you can check https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order_Item_Product.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: than you very much indeed

Comment: No problem @DevelopeCruz. Please accept the answer if it helped you.